# Calculating a variable in an equation to get multiple values

Tags: arrays, sympy, solver, equation-solving

I'm a python beginner and I'm trying to solve a equation. Here is the equation, which I am trying to solve for v:

```
**fSw - ((1)/(1+(Kro*Meu_w)/(Krw*Meu_nw))) = 0**
```

What I would like to do is set a single Meu_w and Meu_nw value and solve for a range of Kro and Krw values. I have tried making Krw and Kro arrays, but when I run my code, the only return I get is "[]". I believe this is an issue with the way I am trying to feed the set of values of Kro and Krw to the equation, i.e. **What I want is to get multiple fSw values after feeding the arrays of Krw and Kro to the equation**, but I'm not sure how to do this.

My code is as follows,

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol

Meu_w = 1
Meu_nw = 2.4

fSw = Symbol('fSw')

Krw = np.array(Krw_fitted)
Kro = np.array(Kro_fitted)

equation = fSw - ((1)/(1+(Kro*Meu_w)/(Krw*Meu_nw)))
solutions = solve(equation,fSw)
print(f"fSw = {solutions}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how SymPy works (with arrays) as you see.

You can make an array of `fSw` values by computing their values for each combination of array values. And since the equation is linear in `fSw` you can solve it once and just use the solution to give values once the array values are substituted:

```py
equation = fSw - ((1)/(1+(Kro*Meu_w)/(Krw*Meu_nw)))
solution = solve(equation, fSw)[0]
M = []
for w in Krw_fitted:
    M.append([])
    for o in Kro_fitted:
        M[-1].append(solution.subs([(Kro,o),(Krw,w)]))

print(Matrix(M))  # will show your array of values
```